# collapsed navbar remains expanded on a Twitter Bootstrap website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a problem with this website

http://www.Ghitulescu.de/beta/index.html

on an iPhone or at small browser windows: the navbar collapse as expected at smaller screen-widths, expands then when clicked on the navbar-toggle BUT when I am choosing one of the navbar-menu-items, the navbar remains like this (and covers more than the half of the iPhone-screen) until I click on the navbar-toggle again.

Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you!

Kind regards,
Vlad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how Bootstrap is designed.

If you would like it do that, add the following code to your site (Tested on Win7 Chrome 32):

```
$('ul.navbar-nav').on('click', function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but: where exactly should I add the code?

Comment: I've tried just before the Google-Analytics code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've got it now: I've placed your code between <script type="text/javascript"> and </script> just before the Google-Analytics code. Thank you - I'll mark as the right answer immediately