# False navigation **only** in Firefox and Opera on a Twitter Bootstrap - Site

Tags: browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have some *really* strange behavior with my site:

http://www.Ghitulescu.de/beta/index.html

build with Twitter Bootstrap 3.

The issue: when clicking on the navbar-items (was / wieviel / wann / wo / wer) the website *jump* to a wrong position.

This problem appears **only** when navigating the website with

a) Firefox (27.0) or
b) Opera (12.16 Build 1860) on my iMac (running OS X 10.9.1) or
c) Internet Explorer (9.0.8112 16421) on a HP EliteBook 8440p (running Windows 7)

**and** when the browser-window is so wide that the navbar is **not collapsed**.

This problem appears **not at all** with:

a) Safari (7.0.1 (9537.73.11))
b) Chrome (32.0.1700.102) on my Mac
c) Mobile Safari, Opera and Chrome on an iPhone 5s & iPad 2 running iOS 7.0.5
d) Chrome (18.0.1025.162) on the same HP mentioned above.

The fact that this issue appears **only when the navbar is not collapsed** reminds me of a question I've put 4 days before here, at stack overflow ([collapsed navbar remains expanded on a Twitter Bootstrap website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653967/collapsed-navbar-remains-expanded-on-a-twitter-bootstrap-website)), regarding the problem that the collapsed navbar stayed extended after clicking... but I really don't know if this is a related problem!

Any ideas?

Comment: 3 more tests on another PC running Windows 7: Safari ok **but** Opera (12.16 Build 1860) and Firefox (14.0.1) not ok! :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved (kudos to MrMurphy http://www.html.de/threads/probleme-beim-navigieren-einer-bootstrap-seite-nur-mit-firefox-opera.51539/): I had put the id's in span-elements instead of h2's!

I have corrected this and have now another problem (at least in all browsers the same! ;-), that I'll post in a separate thread.

Regards,
Vlad